# how do i display a date that is 2 weeks after a set date?

Tags: php, date

If I have a date such as 10/10/10, how do I display the date (in date format) 2 weeks after that? I think it has to do with `strtotime`, but I don't know how to write it. I'm looking at the php.net site and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
date('y/m/d', strtotime('+2 weeks', strtotime('10/10/10')));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% what you need, but we'll give it a try:

```
$defaultTime = strtotime('+2 week',strtotime('10/10/10'));
```

Comment: Mark's answer is more complete.